# Prevent assignment of a type in C

Tags: c, assignment-operator, strong-typing, noncopyable

Given a C function:

```
void f(T x, T y) {
    x = y;
}
```

I want to make sure that all instances of T assignments will fail. So far, the best solution I have is something like:

```
#define T const void *
```

is there a better solution? (Ideally I would like T to be defined as some kind of a non-assignable opaque record pointer type).

Comment: you want to make sure that your function will not compile?

Comment: It's unclear what it is that you want. Do you want `x = y` to generate a compilation error ? Something else ? Do you want to only impact the `f` function ? Or should this be some global behaviour ? How does using `const void*` achieve that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`typedef` is more suitable here.

For immutable data:   `typedef const void * T;`

For immutable pointer: `typedef void * const T;`

Comment: @tohava either you want the pointer to be const or the pointed data. These are 2 different things. the way you used the `#define` you need the first.

Comment: I added a clarification, sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I made a dumb mistake. Apparently,

```
typedef const int T
```

or

```
typedef void * const T
```

work fine for preventing the assignment.